# How to fix '__webpack_require__ is not defined' error in production?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, webpack, babeljs

I'm using webpack 4 to package my scripts in my Asp.net Mvc project which is working fine locally however in production I'm getting the '**webpack_require** is not defined' error. This line '**webpack_require**.r(**webpack_exports**);' in app.js in production seems to be where the issue is coming from. It seems to just be the 'app' script entry that has this issue.

Here is my webpack.config.js

```
   const path = require("path");
   const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");

   module.exports = {
    entry: {
    errorLog: "./Content/Scripts/MyApp/Logs/ErrorLog/index.js",
    user: "./Content/Scripts/MyApp/User/index.js",
    app: "./Content/Scripts/MyApp/app.js",
    },
    output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./Content/Scripts/build"),
    filename: "[name].bundle.min.js"
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            test: "/\.js$/",
            exclude: "/node_modules"
        }
    ]
    },
    plugins: [
    new TerserPlugin({
        parallel: true,
        terserOptions: {
            ecma: 6
        }
    })
   ]
}
```